# Russian equivalents of the rhetorical construction "What is there to talk about / understand?"

Tags: выражения

> А чего там говорить-то?
>
> А чего там понимать-то?
>
> А о чем тут разговаривать-то?

I'm wondering if these phrasings work and which is a better fit: "там" or "тут".

How do native speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: your question actually is about difference of usage "там" and "тут" in this particular set of phrases, that said, your title is slightly misleading.

Comment: It seems to me the choice depends on the degree of relation of an affair to the speaker, **там** will rather be used in relation to affairs of other people, either 2nd or 3d person.

Comment: Can't think of a rule here. Much depends on situation and personal feelings. I tend to say "там" so as not to be involved, kind of create some distance between myself and the situation.

Answer (score 2):

> Что тут скажешь?
>   Здесь разговаривать не о чем.
>   С кем там разговаривать?
>   О чем с ним говорить?

It all depends on the situation. But you are in a way right, там is about a third person situation, and тут is nearer. But тут is more general and can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Native speakers likely will say **"О чем тут [еще] говорить?"** / **"Что тут еще понимать? [Тут и так всё ясно!]"**.